# Syntax error notification in native code in Eclipse using the newest NDK r8d

Tags: android, android-ndk

While opening C++ source file in Eclipse editor, there I can see syntax error notifications while using ndk-r8d. They are not real errors, but additional CDT configuring is required according to internet tutorial.

For that I Opened Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols and added the Include paths for C++ for ndk r8d.

But still the errors notification exists. Please provide some solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience is that Eclipse often gives wrong errors for c++ projects, even if it compiles correctly. This is because the runtime c++ checker is not perfect.

My solution was to turn off all checks in the Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Code Analysis. This way, there's no live feedback, but all errors shown are at least *real*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a temporal fixes.

1. Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> Providers
2. Check "CDT GCC Build Output Parser" (you may can check the others)
3. Try clean and rebuild.

When I checked 'Use global provider shared between project', I got reliable header resolve result.