# Eclipse shows error, while ndk_build is successful

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am doing Java Native Development for android. And I use Android NDK and eclipse as IDE. Very frequently I write a C/C++ code in jni and eclipse shows errors such as:

Could not be resolved:

1. JNIEXPORT
2. JNICALL
3. JNIEnv
4. jobject
5. jint

But on the other hand `ndk-build` builds the .so file sucessfully without any error or even warnings. How to fix this in eclipse?

If you need here is the code I compile:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int multiply(int i, int j) {
         int x = i * j;
         return x;
}

extern "C" {
         JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_cookbook_chapter3_HelloNDKGDBActivity_multiply(JNIEnv* env, jobject o, jint pi, jint pj){
           int i = 1, j = 0;
           while (i) {
             j=(++j)/100;
           }
           return multiply(pi, pj);
        }
}
```

Comment: Those are all defined in jni.h.  Are you including it?

Comment: Of course, otherwise `ndk-build` would fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to refresh project tree. Very frequently eclipse shows error, why when you click on the project and press `F5` (refresh), errors are gone. But is they don't then please try the approach below:

> turn off all checks in the Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Code
>   Analysis

See actual answer here: [Syntax error notification in native code in Eclipse using the newest NDK r8d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255949/syntax-error-notification-in-native-code-in-eclipse-using-the-newest-ndk-r8d)

Answer (score 0):

I've already had these kind of issues. I don't know if it's your case, but, it might be. Anyway, my CDT eclipse plugin does not work very well and every time I edit or even open a C/C++ file, it gets full of errors. But, I can change my files normally and the ndk-build works properly. Have you tried another C/C++ file editor? It can be a solution to stop getting these errors.

Comment: Have used TextWrangler editor and magic - that helped. :) Also I have copied the dode from a .pdf file using `Preview`. Maybe this was a reason too, I don't know. But thanks :)

Comment: But I guess this is not the only way it occurs. It can occur without any reason too. I have even removed CDT, NDK and re-downloaded them to fix it. I think Eclipse is not a stable IDE.

Comment: It's better to set these configurations that you've listed bellow on Eclipse Properties (Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Code Analysis). This way, you won't have to apply them every time you use some native code file.